# Live CMSampleBuffer processing

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to process CMSampleBuffers on the go, but I quickly stop receiving samples, even though I'm copying the samples and processing the copies.

I get the samples with the AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate and process them like that:

```
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if (bufferCopy != nil) {
        bufferCopy == nil
    }

    if CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, &bufferCopy) == noErr {

        let encodedSamples = self.encoder.encodeSample(bufferCopy?.takeRetainedValue())
        println(encodedSamples.count)
        CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBuffer)
//            println("Copy: \(bufferCopy!.takeRetainedValue())")
        }
        else {
            println("Failed to copy sampleBuffer")
        }
    }
```

Objective-C solution would work too.

I also created a GitHub repo with this example: https://github.com/Devxhkl/SwiftAudioStreamingOggOpus

Comment: typo == nil. Also setting to nil is probably not what you want to do, zero out the mem or flush the buffer. Haven't thoroughly checked issue, just noticed